# Putting ajax and non-ajax actions in the same controller in CakePHP

Tags: cakephp

I've run into a problem in my CakePHP app as a result of adding some ajax actions.

My table is called `orders` so obviously my controller is called `OrdersController` and the model is called `Order`

It is my understanding of CakePHP's best practices that if I am going to run any logic on the `Order` model, that it should be done in the `OrdersController`. This is fine for the basic CRUD stuff but now that some of my views need to send ajax requests to manipulate `Order` data I have a problem.

The problem is that for ajax to work properly, I have to put this at the beginning of the `OrdersController`

```
var $layout = 'ajax';  // uses an empty layout
var $autoRender=false; // renders nothing by default
```

Then, to stop the security component interfering with my Ajax form submissions, I also need this:

```
public function beforeFilter() {
    parent::beforeFilter();
    $this->Security->csrfUseOnce = false;
    $this->Security->csrfExpires = '+1 hour';
}
```

None of this would be a problem if the controller was only being used for Ajax requests, but the problem is that it's being used for regular Cake actions too.

Is the answer that I should have two controllers? One for regular actions and one for ajax actions? This doesn't seem to be mentioned in the Cake docs and it doesn't seem like a very efficient way of doing things.

I know I can change the layout and possibly the auto-render setting on a per-action basis, but I don't see how it's possible to do this with the csrf settings, which need to be in the beforeFilter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No need for a separate controller. Use cakes request handler. In your controller method, you can test if it's an Ajax request.

```
if ($this->request->is('ajax')) {
    //set to Ajax layout and security settings, etc
```

You'll need to include the request handler component at the top of your controller:

```
public $components = array('RequestHandler');
```

See this page in the cook book For more info: http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/components/request-handling.html

Comment: thank you very much, that's exactly what I meant. Also, the link you provided shows how I can put conditionals in the beforeFilter which is perfect for the csrf stuff.